# iPhoneでのバウンススクロールを無効にするには

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari

Ruby on Railsの練習でTwitterのようなサイトを作っているのですが、バウンズスクロールを無効にする方法がどうしてもわかりません。
MacOS（Chrome等）ではバウンズスクロールを無効化出来たのですが、iPhoneでのバウンズスクロールがどうしても出来ません。

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

で個別の要素に`height: 100%;` `overflow: auto;`にするとバウンズスクロールは無効化出来たのですがこれだとSafariの下部と上部にあるバーがスクロールしても小さくならず常に上下にバーが表示されてしまうようになってしまいます。

TwitterをSafariで開くとバウンズスクロールはしないがスクロールするとちゃんと上下にあるバーが縮む様になっていました。
Twitterのようにオーバースクロールを無効かつ上下のバーをスクロールしたときに縮むようにするにはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。

CSSなどに詳しい方教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: iPhone を持っていないので明確なことは言えないのですが、この場合 [iNoBounce](https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce) というライブラリは使えませんか？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/234713